# Unable to find APK file when running Appium test

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, appium-android, appium-ios

I have a .APK file on Eclipse that I am calling but when call it and run appium I am getting an error message.  I am trying to use the absolute path but still I get the error below....

This is my code I believe the issue is in the

```
 caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "ANDROID");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.1");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Nexus 7");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "0911b4aa");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 60);
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "disk0s2⁩/Users⁩/⁨anthonywalker/eclipse-workspace⁩/Android_F1_TV⁩/src⁩/test⁩/resources⁩/⁨apps⁩/app-playstore-preprod-debug.apk⁩");
//      caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
        URL url = new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub");
```

Eclipse set up....

[image]

```
Error returned on the console.....
```

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The application at '/Android_F1_TV/src/test/resources/apps/app-playstore-preprod-debug (1).apk' does not exist or is not accessible

Error returned in Appium....

[debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: The application at '/Android_F1_TV/src/test/resources/apps/app-playstore-preprod-debug (1).apk' does not exist or is not accessible

Answer (score 1):

Is this the absolute path from your `C:` drive? My `.apk` file paths usually look like `C:\Users\username\Repository\MyProjectDirectory\myApk.apk`. If `Android_F1_TV` is your project directory, you will also need to pre-pend the path to your project before that. Something like `C:\Users\username\Projects\Android_F1_TV\src\test\resources\apps`.

To test out your path, you could open File Explorer and try pasting `/Android_F1_TV/src/test/resources/apps` into your File Explorer path, hit enter, and see if you are taken to the correct directory of your `.apk`. File explorer will show you an error saying the path is not found, if it is invalid.

My only other guess would be the `()` in your `.apk` file name -- these special characters shouldn't matter, but if the above solution does not work then you could try to rename your APK and remove the `()` to see if that helps.

Comment: Hi Christie,  I am still not having any success.  I've change when my APK file was stored as it was in applications and I've added it to a Eclipse workspace.  Above added a bit more detail and a screen shot of my Eclipse set up,  I am also on  MAC Thanks

Comment: Could you try replacing the hardcoded .apk path with something dynamic using `System.getProperty("user.dir"));` to get the current working directory? My only other guess is something wrong with the .apk itself. You could pull a simple .apk like Photos or Calculator .apk and test to see if that works too.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use appPackage ? this is my exemple and its working fine :

```
desired_caps["appPackage"] = "com.wci.android.yourappname.uat"
desired_caps["appActivity"] = "com.wci.android.yourappactiviti.presentation.activities.SplashActivity"
```

Comment: I also managed to overcome the same problem by installing the app on the via adb in commandline, skipping "app" desired capability and specifying "appPackage" capability instead